# Is this text extraction scenario possible in linux bash shell?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

Let's say my text file is like this

> Person1 :                movie1
>           (space and tab)  : movie 2
>            (space and tab)  : movie 3
>            (space and tab)  : movie 4

I want to find for a particular movie, the actor. 
So here is how I am going about doing this.

> Do a grep cat actors | grep 'movie3'

This will give me line 3 which is an empty line up unitl movie3 appears. So if somehow I can get the first line before this particular line which follows this pattern

> grep '^[^ \t]*.*'(does not start with a space)

it has to be the line with the actor's name in this movie.(I don't care about movie one there)

Is there any combination of sed/grep/awk which can help me do it in shell? I hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Bill Murray <- *Groundhog Day* <- grep with Perl mode Magic**

It's a bit tricky, but you can use this:

```
grep -P "(?sm)^\S+[^:\r\n]*?(?=\s*:(?:(?!^\S).)*?Groundhog Day)" mymoviefile
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/gS0lJ5).

- `-P` activates Perl mode
- `(?sm)` turns on two mode modifiers:
- `s` activates `DOTALL` mode, allowing the dot to match across lines
- `m` turns on multi-line mode, allowing `^` and `$` to match on each line
- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the line
- `\S+` matches one or more non-space chars
- `[^:\r\n]*?` lazily matches any non-colon, non-newline chars, up to ...
- the point where the lookahead `(?=\s*:(?:(?!^\S).)*?Groundhog Day)` can assert, without consuming chars, that what follows is...
- `\s*:` optional spaces and a colon
- then `(?:(?!^\S).)*` zero or more chars that are not a non-space char at the beginning of a line, lazily matching up to...
- `Groundhog Day` the movie title!

---

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: I tried running it. It did not work. Here is the error message grep: unrecognized character after (? or (?-. I am trying to debug it, but since It is very complex, and I don't known of half the things you have used here, I think I will need your further help. :^D

Comment: Added tweak and tweak, have a look. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help.But it is definitely not for the faint hearted.

Comment: Finished the explanation. ` it is definitely not for the faint hearted` You're right, it's far from obvious, but with the explanation I'm sure you'll be able to understand it. Is it working?

Comment: After that explanation, I actually owe you 50-60 reputation at least! :)

Comment: Nah, it was a real pleasure, you're most welcome! :) If you want to do me (or you) a favor, go learn some more cool regex! :) For instance there are a few interesting questions in the right pane of my profile, the [regex FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075) is also good, then answers by some of the regex gods here (click on top users of all time in the regex tag), or sites like regular-expressions.info and rexegg... Regex is cool, Dude! :)

Answer (score 3):

I would do it with awk if I unserstood the problem right:

```
 awk -F: -v s="$search" '$1~/\S/{p=$1}$2~s{print $1 FS $2}' file
```

test with `movie 3`:

```
kent$ cat f
Person1 : movie1
          : movie 2
          : movie 3
          : movie 4
```

in above file, there are leading spaces/tabs

```
kent$  awk -F: -v s="movie 3" '$1~/\S/{p=$1}$2~s{print p FS $2}' f
Person1 : movie 3
```

Comment: I created a file just like yours, no leading space in the line with person1: movie1. and I ran the exact  command, you gave me. It gave just this, (start of line):movie 3.

Comment: I am on linux. It is expected to work there, in case you ran it on mac?

Comment: @Dude I only have linux. I guess because your gawk version is lower than mine, you could try: `awk ... '$1~/[^ \t]/{....}'`

Comment: Yup it worked. If you don't mind, could you please explain the regex briefly.

Comment: @Dude the regex is just matching a string ($1, the first column) if it contains any non-empty char. The problem like that is typical for awk.  grep is great, but here it is not the right tool for it.(my opinion)

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^\S/h;/movie 3/{H;x;s/:.*:/:/p}' file
```

Use the `-n` switch to provide grep like nature. Save the person in the hold space and append the movie to it. Then remove unwanted text and print out.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit obscure but get the job done:

```
awk '/^[^ ]/{p=0} /Person1/{p=1} p'
```

Example:

Input file:

```
Person1 : movie1
    : movie 2
    : movie 3
    : movie 4
Person2 : movie 5
    : movie 6
```

Execution:

```
awk '/^[^ ]/{p=0} /Person1/{p=1} p' file
Person1 : movie1
    : movie 2
    : movie 3
    : movie 4

awk '/^[^ ]/{p=0} /Person2/{p=1} p' file
Person2 : movie 5
    : movie 6
```

**OBS:** In the command line the output is indented.

Explanation:

1. If the line does not start with space, sets p=0
2. If the line contains Person1 sets p=1
3. if p=1 then print (This part is obscure)

Can be done in `perl` too:

```
perl -ne '/^\w+/ && {$p=0}; /Person1/ && {$p=1}; $p && {print}'
```